# css3 columns without cutting paragraphs

Tags: css

Im trying to set a series of  in a column layout. Ive been trying with CSS3 but it cuts the elemens in half. Heres an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/zh9zq/

Is it possible to have the columns not cut certain elements in half? Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by "cuts the elements in half"? It looks exactly like it should for me in FF11.

Comment: Im not saying that it behaves wrong. im saying, that I would like if a WHOLE paragraph wouldnt be cut, and it could stay together in a single column, and THEN the next paragraph in the next column

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Solution found:

```
-webkit-column-break-inside:avoid;
-moz-column-break-inside:avoid;
-o-column-break-inside:avoid;
-ms-column-break-inside:avoid;
column-break-inside:avoid;
```

Comment: It is convinient to say, that this rules must be on element, that is mean to not break, no on cover or parent element (columned element)