# CSS3: Prevent block from spanning columns

Tags: html, css

[Example jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/slolife/cHcfQ/4/), but make sure you use a new browser that supports one of the following to view:

```
-moz-column-count: 3;
-webkit-columns: 3;
-o-columns: 3;
columns: 3;
```

Using the new CSS3 column attribute, I'd like to see if there is a way to prevent a  block of text from being spanned across columns.  What I have is a three column layout inside a div using columns:3 and dt/dd tags and text inside of that. So the browser automatically makes the columns for me.  But I don't want the dt and associated dd tags to span two columns.  Is there a way to wrap the dt and dd tags together so that the browser will grow the column down, rather than splitting up the content?

Same with paragraph tags: can I tell the browser not to span a paragraph, instead make the column taller?

Comment: Have you looked at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6424088/css-column-breaks-not-doing-anything?

Comment: Closing this one.  It is a dup of a number of other questions, but I didn't know to search for column-break-inside

Comment: possible duplicate of [css3 columns without cutting paragraphs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9784239/css3-columns-without-cutting-paragraphs)